# Devexpress How to change progress bar color

Tags: colors, devexpress, progress-bar

I have problem about progress bar (DevExpress) v9.2.4.0.
My color progress is blue,and i wanna re-colored from red to blue.
thanks for your concern and GBU

Comment: Winform, asp.net?

Comment: Assuming you're using WinForms, you have to disable skinning for the control, as the skinning mechanisms will override the appearance settings.

Comment: VB.NET not asp.NET,

Answer (score 0):

Progressbar1.Properties.StartColor = Color.DarkRed; // choose the color
Progressbar1.Properties.EndColor = Color.Green;  // choose the color